# Render Error: Shoud have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue

Tags: react-native

When I added the Tooltips function in my code, it showed a Render Error. I tried to add the key but it's still not working and it also causes another page to have this same error.

Could you please help me find a solution?

for the error in the Source is there have an error in react.development.js and the error is at the useState. return dispatcher.useState(initialState,xxxxxxxx)

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { GestureResponderEvent, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import Icon1 from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { typography } from '../../utils';
import { HomeStackParamList } from './home';
import Header from '@components/header';
import Tooltip from 'react-native-walkthrough-tooltip';

export interface HeaderProps {
  rightItems?: {
    icon: string;
    iconSet: 'Feather' | 'AntDesign';
    onPress?: (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void;
    tooltipText?: string;
  }[];
  withSearch?: boolean;
  alternateTitle?: string;
}

const header = (
  stackScreenProps: NativeStackScreenProps<HomeStackParamList>,
  headerProps: HeaderProps
) => {
  const { route, navigation } = stackScreenProps;
  const { rightItems, withSearch } = headerProps;
  const [isTooltipVisible, setIsTooltipVisible] = React.useState(false);

  if (withSearch !== undefined)
    return { header: () => <Header {...{ withSearch }} /> };
  return {
    headerTitle: () => (
      <Text style={typography.heading2}>
        {headerProps.alternateTitle
          ? headerProps.alternateTitle
          : route.name.split('_').join(' ')}
      </Text>
    ),
    headerLeft: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
        <Icon name="chevron-left" size={24} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    headerRight: () =>
      rightItems?.map(({ icon, iconSet, onPress, tooltipText }) => (
        <View style={{ marginLeft: 20 }} key={`${icon}-${iconSet}`}>
          {tooltipText ? (
            <Tooltip isVisible={isTooltipVisible} content={<Text>{tooltipText}</Text>} backgroundColor="gray">
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsTooltipVisible(true)}>
                {iconSet === 'Feather' ? (
                  <Icon name={icon} size={24} />
                ) : (
                  <Icon1 name={icon} size={24} />
                )}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Tooltip>
          ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity {...{ onPress }}>
              {iconSet === 'Feather' ? (
                <Icon name={icon} size={24} />
              ) : (
                <Icon1 name={icon} size={24} />
              )}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        </View>
      )),
  };
};

export default header;
```